# How do I create inline-block campaign content using Adobe Target

Tags: css, adobe, mbox, find-replace, test-and-target

[Test & Target](http://www.slideshare.net/AntonioGarcia10/test-and-target-book) code generates divs with style attributes that include `display:block`. How do I replace this with `inline-block`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `!important` declaration in the style sheet to override the mbox div, the generated div and descendants of the container ID:

```
div[style*='block'], #foo > div[style*='block'] 
  { 
  display: inline-block !important;
  vertical-align: top;
  }

div.mboxDefault 
  {
  display: inline-block !important; visibility: visible; }
  }
```

Append the following query string to the URL parameters to toggle the mboxes:

- ?mboxDisable=1 (mbox Off)
- ?mboxDebug=1 (mbox On)

Use mousemove if you need to bind events to the mboxes instead of the load or ready events.

**References**

- [Multivariate Testing Buyer's Guide](http://www.slideshare.net/AntonioGarcia10/multivariate-testingbuyersguide-1)
- [mbox.js Changelog](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/target/ov/r_mboxjs_change_log.html)
- [Adobe Target Product Documentation](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/target/index.html)